# Java encryption on-the-fly by virtual drive

Tags: java, windows, encryption, on-the-fly

I have made an encryption system and I'm looking for a way to add some way to integrate it with file system on windows(if possible also on linux). I don't want to rise a debate whether it is needed, that it already exists etc...

I was hoping to find a way to mount a virtual disk drive that will be able to access the files in the decrypted form, encrypt and decrypt on the fly using my software, it is currently written in java, but if needed I can port it to c++.

I have found one way to do it, which is to run a java ssh server and use another software to mount it in windows, but it doesn't work work well, constant crashes or it sometimes just doesn't mount the drive.

I need it as I want to access the files using IDE and other programs without coping the files as it decreases the security and doubles the disk space used.

Has anyone found a way to do it preferably in java?

Is there some kind of API for it (all I need is list files, get parent, read file, write file)?

Or is there a good java lib what works with another program to do it?

Comment: If I understand your question, then no. There is no way to integrate your user mode Java code into an Operating System level device driver on Windows. In Linux it might be possible with a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) driver... but I would not expect such an implementation to be *easy*.

Comment: Yes you understand it correctly, I guess I'm stuck with using external program to mount the ssh java server. I don't mind it being hard, I can get almost everything to work, but I have no experience with virtual disk drive or drivers. Would you happen to know a good ssh java server lib, I'm using Apache Mina sshd, but it crashes a lot?

Comment: I have got rid of the crashes (I'm using Mina sshd 0.7 with NetDrive2), but it is running at 20MB/s on non-encrypted files, which is really slow, the encryption I'm using runs at 60-70MB/s on a single thread.